# How to increase range of a NVR using router whilst ipcam are hardcoded to NVR network and there's no way it seems to update them

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, https

I studied network a decade ago and I almost forgotten everything, not sure where to start to extend range of my NVR using a router.

This is how the wireless IPCam look like, as I don't understand chinese language, I am unable to find any documentation on these, even if I try to connect them using lan cable to my laptop and try to go to 172.20.14.30 to access IPCAM's ui, it doesn't work... even though lan port cable shows green light blinking
[image]

My NVR's network settings are as following:
[image]

NVR's shows IPCAM's ip addresses as following:
[image]

IPCAM connect to NVR using these wireless settings, if i change NVR's wifi name then ipcams don't connect anymore:
[image]

I have this wavlink router:
https://www.wavlink.com/en_us/product/WL-WN529R2P.html

It has these settings and it's connected to another internet router using WISP:
[image]

and it's LAN setup is this:
[image]